# nodejs auth into ADFS using SAML

Tags: node.js, saml, adfs

I am new to ADFS system, the application that I built uses a microservice architecture, in the login process service 1 sends a request via body to service 2 for validation then sends a response whether it was successful or not to service 1, this process is running normally.However, currently there is a need for requests sent to service 2 to be validated to ADFS first. If successful then it will continue, but if not then an error response will be sent to service 1,**how do i do it** ?

The following is an example of code for service 2 before using ADFS

routes file :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const login = require('../controllers/LoginController.js');


router.post('/account/api/v1/login', login.doLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

how do I send the request body to ADFS for validation ?